# Unzipping attachment - Run-time error '91'

Tags: vba, outlook

I found this code on another website. It should take an email found in an Outlook folder and unzip the attachment. It uses a temporary location to do this.

I am using Outlook 2013 and the references I am using are: Visual Basic for Application, Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library. I am running this code currently in a module.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Unzip1()
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Atchmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace '
    Dim FSO As Object               'variables for unzipping
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim FileNameFolder As Variant

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("ASE")

    For Each msg In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atchmt In msg.Attachments
            If (Right(Atchmt.FileName, 3) = "zip") Then
                FileNameFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "Documents\"
                Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                oApp.NameSpace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace(Atchmt.FileName).Items
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I am getting an error "Object variable or With block variable not set" on this line.

```
oApp.NameSpace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace(Atchmt.FileName).Items
```

Comment: Your missing `Atchmt.SaveAsFile FileNameFolder` after `FileNameFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "Documents\"`

Answer (score 2):

I had to change

`DIm oAPP as Object`

to

`Dim oApp as Shell`

Early-binding using '***Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation***'. Not sure why it was complaining about the late-binding

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about the [Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.namespace.aspx) class from the Outlook object mode, it doesn't provide the CopyHere method. The object itself provides methods for logging in and out, accessing storage objects directly by ID, accessing certain special default folders directly, and accessing data sources owned by other users. Use `GetNamespace("MAPI")` to return the Outlook NameSpace object from the Application object.

The [CopyHere](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx) method copies an item or items to a folder. The item or items to copy should be passed as a parameter. **This can be a string that represents a file name, a FolderItem object, or a FolderItems object.** But not the attachment filename. You need to save the attachment on the disk first.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Sub Folder ("Books") in your Email Inbox Exist &  "\Documents\Files\" that's where unzip files will be saved

```
Option Explicit
Sub Unzip1()
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Atchmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace '
    Dim FSO As Object               'variables for unzipping
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim FileNameFolder As Variant

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Books")

    For Each msg In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atchmt In msg.Attachments
            If (Right(Atchmt.FileName, 3) = "zip") Then
                FileNameFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Files\"
                Atchmt.SaveAsFile FileNameFolder 
                Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                oApp.NameSpace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace(Atchmt.FileName).Items
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Omar, now I am getting a Run-timer error '13' on Line 16.  `For Each msg In SubFolder.Items`  I am running this code in a module.

Comment: @Bigotacon see my updated answer copy the code and run it, I have tested and it works, make sure you have the correct file path \Documents\Files\ - OR -  \My Documents\Files\`

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong then. I am still getting a file mismatch issue. I am getting it with the original code now and with your improved code. I keep trying so I can accept your answer when I fix it. Thank you sir.

Comment: After I put another email in the zip folder I am now getting our old friend Run-time error on line 24. `oApp.NameSpace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace(Atchmt.FileName).Items`

Comment: @Bigotacon  what outlook version are you using also try fixing the following line `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")`  if your still getting error  try editing your question with new code so i can see there if your missing anything.

Comment: I am using Outlook 2013 and I copied and pasted the code that I am using now. You should find that it is the same as yours.

Comment: @Bigotacon you are missing `"\"` on the following line `"Documents\"` it needs look like this `"\Documents\"` i test on 2010 but as soon as i get chance i will try to test on 2013